# NPM always ask me for root in a Express project

Tags: node.js, express, root

Since I use Express.js, I can't use `npm install` normally anymore. I always have to go root for it to work...

Let's say I generate a projet with

```
express --sessions --css css
```

When I try to do a `npm install` after, I've got these errors

```
npm WARN package.json application-name@0.0.1 No README.md file found!
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, open '/Users/Arnaud/.npm/e7d16cae-express-3-1-1.lock'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, open '/Users/Arnaud/.npm/e7d16cae-express-3-1-1.lock']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/Arnaud/.npm/e7d16cae-express-3-1-1.lock' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.3.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/Arnaud/Sites/test
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.2
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.15
npm ERR! path /Users/Arnaud/.npm/e7d16cae-express-3-1-1.lock
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, open '/Users/Arnaud/.npm/e7d16cae-express-3-1-1.lock'
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Arnaud/Sites/test/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

But if do a `sudo npm install`, it's all good... Any idea why ?

Comment: The file `/Users/Arnaud/.npm/e7d16cae-express-3-1-1.lock` probably belongs to root (perhaps a leftover from once running `npm` as root). I think you can just remove it and try again. Otherwise, check the permissions of `/Users/Arnaud/.npm/` to make sure its writable for you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is probably a permissions issue. To reclaim ownership of the `/Users/Arnaud/.npm` directory execute the following command in the terminal

```
chown -R Arnaud /Users/Arnaud/.npm
```

If you are on OSX you can also use Disk Utility to repair permissions across the entire disk, which will probably fix the issue for you as well.

Comment: Yup, it did. Weird thing is I did try to repair permissions with the Disk Utility and it didn't solved anything... Anyway, it works now. Thanks :)

Comment: I had to do sudo chown -R username /Users/username/.npm

Comment: Anyone know the command for this on ubuntu? whenever I try to `npm install -g anyThing` I have to rerun it with `sudo` in front

Comment: @ConnorLeech It should be similar on unix. `chown -R \`whoami\` ~/.npm` for the home directory (npm install), and `chown -R \`whoami\` /usr/local/lib/node_modules/` for the global directory (npm install -g)

Comment: I don't have a node_modules in lib

Answer (score 0):

If your using a MAC OS or a Unix/Lunix machine, you just need to be aware that for a security measure even if your to root owner you need to use the **sudo** command on the command line in the terminal. So changing ownership of files and directories is not enough with chown command most of time.

The reason is that the command you will execute will have big changes on system files and you need to enter the password of your root admin, just like in Windows when they ask you to enter the administrator password for system changes, so it will look like this:

*Ms-MacBook-Pro:~ AMB$ **sudo** npm install -g express-generator

**Password:** (ENTER YOUR PASSWORD FOR THE ROOT/ADMINISTRATOR)

```
/usr/local/bin/express -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/express-generator/bin/express-cli.js
/usr/local/lib
└─┬ express-generator@4.15.0 
  ├─┬ commander@2.9.0 
  │ └── graceful-readlink@1.0.1 
  ├── ejs@2.5.6 
  ├─┬ mkdirp@0.5.1 
  │ └── minimist@0.0.8 
  └── sorted-object@2.0.1
```

Ms-MacBook-Pro:~ AMB$*