# Why does npm need sudo for EVERYTHING?

Tags: macos, node.js, shell, npm

I don't know how I've managed it but npm seems to need `sudo` for absolutely every command, even `npm help` does not work without sudo. If I use a command without `sudo`, I do not see am `EACCESS` error, but instead my terminal session hangs and then just closes that tab (I use iTerm on Mac).

I have tried changing the ownership of my local `.npm` folder, outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15950676/91359) and also done the same on my `/usr/local/bin` folder where node is installed but none of these allow me to just run npm without `sudo`, even when installing local packages...! It seems to me that something has screwed along the way, can anyone help?

Many thanks

Answer (score 6):

I encountered the same error after a fresh install of 0.12.4 today; this solved the problem for me:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

In my particular case, I noticed that this folder was owned by '{some-large-integer-account}:wheel'...YMMV

If that doesn't solve it, take a look at the ownership of the folders that are being blocked as mentioned in the EACCESS error trace. If you're not sure what the ownership *should* be, you can usually infer it from the sibling dirs' ownership.

Answer (score 0):

I had this as well on my machine. What I did to fix it (there are probably much less extreme ways) was to completely remove npm, and then did a fresh installation node.js (with which npm is included) from http://nodejs.org/ making sure I didn't install as root. That then allowed me to use npm without root (except for global installs).

Comment: I tried that earlier today actually but perhaps I didn't uninstall as well as I could have. It would still be nice to know why this is happening... I'll let you know how it goes

Comment: Mine was happening because the npm folders had been installed in root owner folders, whereas the new install put them folders my non-root user owned (the user dir). Maybe yours is the same.

Comment: So what should I do? I have removed node/npm and reinstalled again through `brew`. I am back where I started and none the wiser. I came across [this](https://github.com/sindresorhus/guides/blob/master/npm-global-without-sudo-linux.md) recently but cannot get it to work. I don't think I can be bothered to figure it out anymore though - it shouldn't be this hard and I can't believe I'm one of the few experiencing this problem..

Answer (score 0):

Take ember project for example, I give all related project directory root:

`neil@neil-System-Product-Name:~/Projects/ember-quickstart$ sudo chown -R $(whoami) /home/neil/Projects/ember-quickstart/`


`neil@neil-System-Product-Name:~/Projects/ember-quickstart$ ember s
Could not start watchman
Visit https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#watchman for more info.
Livereload server on http://localhost:7020
Build successful (10679ms) – Serving on http://localhost:4200/
Slowest Nodes (totalTime => 5% )              | Total (avg)

----------------------------------------------+---------------------
Babel (18)                                    | 7561ms (420 ms)

Concat (8)                                    | 1872ms (234 ms)

Rollup (1)                                    | 629ms`

Answer (score 0):

Use the below option.

Open the terminal and `cd` to your `Home` directory and run the below command.

```
mkdir "${HOME}/.npm-packages"
```

Then this command after that.

```
npm config set prefix "${HOME}/.npm-packages"
```

Next, open your `.zshrc` file using the `open -t .zshrc` command and add the following to it.

```
NPM_PACKAGES="${HOME}/.npm-packages"

export PATH="$PATH:$NPM_PACKAGES/bin"

# Preserve MANPATH if you already defined it somewhere in your config.
# Otherwise, fall back to `manpath` so we can inherit from `/etc/manpath`.
export MANPATH="${MANPATH-$(manpath)}:$NPM_PACKAGES/share/man"
```