# How to solve PhantomJS not found on PATH on OS X?

Tags: npm, npm-install

How am I supposed to solve the `PhantomJS not found on PATH` on OS X. I mention its the standard dev environment where node was installed using brew.

> /usr/local/bin/node
>    v5.7.1
>
> /usr/local/bin/npm
>   3.6.0

I get this warning in too many npm packages and I just want to fix it. It seems that doing `npm install -g phantomjs-prebuilt` does not do the trick because it does not install it in the path.

> Done. Phantomjs binary available at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs

Is there a command that can assure that npm install binaries in `PATH`?

Answer (score -3):

First of all, you could remove npm and use an installer.
Also, the second answer could be useful here:
[Why does npm need sudo for EVERYTHING?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20114901/why-does-npm-need-sudo-for-everything)